# Use FOSUserBundle in relation with yml-based Entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I've started a Symfony2 project from scratch where I then installed **FOSUserBundle**.

Then, I have written (actually, generated with ORM Designer) some entities that need to have relations between them, and with the User entity.

I have `Items` belonging to `Users`, `Collections` belonging to `Users` that group `Items`, and so on.

Since I used FOSUserBundle I only have a basic User class (https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md , step 3a) defined using annotations, no `config/doctrine` folder and no `User.yml` file in it.

I then created the `MyBundle/Resources/config/doctrine` folder and added the `yml` files mentioned above.

When I try to generate the entities with the command-line tool everything works fine: it will create the Entities from my yml files.

However, at this point, trying to load up in browsers the url where the login previously worked (when I only had the **FOSUserBundle** installed) will throw this error:

> MappingException: No mapping file found named
>   '/var/www/concert/src/X/MyBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/User.orm.yml'
>   for class 'X\MyBundle\Entity\User'.

Following actions, such as generating the CRUD logic, will not work as long as I have an `*.orm.ym`l file in the `config/doctrine` folder. If I remove those, CRUD generation will work, but generation of actual mysql tables won't.

Juggling with these gets me to a point where I can also get the tables, but then the actual app doesn't work if I try to use any of the url's where the newly generated CRUD is involved because since the entities are based on yml (which I remove to get things "working") it won't have any mapping knowledge.

Is this inherently wrong? To have yml-based entities in relationship with an User entity based on the FOSUserBundle and still be able to get the nice command-line generation tools?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you describe stems from mixing configuration formats (yaml and I assume annotations). You can easily fix this by ditching the annotations in your models and replacing them with yaml-files like you would do in your own models.

Unfortunately the FOSUserBundle-docs only show you how to use annotations, so here is a quick transformation into yaml format when your X\MyBundle\Entity\User extends FOSUSerBundle's UserEntity:

```
X\MyBundle\Entity\User:
    type:  entity
    table: fos_user
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            strategy: { generator: "AUTO" }
```

The remaining stuff is taken care of by FOSUserBundle, as the BaseModel is a [mapped-superclass](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) and already describes the stuff in the `User.orm.xml`, but you could just as well replace the existing values or add additional values just like you would do with your own models.

If you don't use annotations throughout your app, you might also want to disable them in your `app/config/config.yml` to prevent side effects.

Comment: That totally did it. I had suspected it had to be some sort of hint I could give to Symfony to acheive this. One observation to that is that I need to also add a line in the User.orm.yml to define the table mapping, because by default it will look for a table called user, so I added table: fos_user (the name I inherited when I generated the user table from the fos bundle).

Comment: Oops, you're right the `table: fos_user` is mentioned in the docs, but I missed it in the yaml. Will fix it right away.

Comment: How do you configure the Inheritance? I try this but `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` returns `CREATE TABLE fos_user (id INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB`. It doesn't add the inheritance columns.

Comment: @BraisGabin Are you sure you followed the directions in the FOSUserBundle documentation? It seems like you forget the part where you have to declare the fos_user-class in your config.yml or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problem was that `X\MyBundle\Entity\User` inherited from `FOS\UserBundle\Document\User` instead of `FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User`.

Comment: @Aris just like you do with the rest of your xml-/yml-configs for your doctrine-entities. By default it's in your bundle's `Resources/config/doctrine/` -folder and the yml filename corresponds with your entity, so `User.yml`