# Symfony2 After installing FOSUserBundle, DoctrineFixturesBundle looks for a User.orm.yml - what to put in?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

In my Symfony2 app, I am using the following (among others) bundles:

app/AppKernel.php

```
new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle(),
```

FOSUserBundle was working fine, until I added some fixtures. Now, DoctrineFixturesBundle is looking for an extension of my User.php

The error: MappingException: No mapping file found named 'MyBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/User.orm.yml'

I Defined the user class per the FOSUserBundle instructions -

User_class: 'MyBundle\Entity\User'  but just cut & pasted the default in the instructions- I have no need for other data at this point.

The question - what do I put and where, to get this project back working again?  I've tried an empty MyBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/User.orm.yml, I've tried a dummy file, I am just lost.

Thanks!

Comment: You are mixing different configuration styles (annotation and yaml) which can cause problems. Please refer to this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984344/use-fosuserbundle-in-relation-with-yml-based-entities/14988359#14988359

Comment: yes, that's it.  I guess if multiple people have the same problem, then the docs should be updated to reflect it. I'll do a pull request on the docs.  Thanks for your help!